Invalid date when setting one computer's clock from another
I have the following code in a Bash script, which takes the current date/time and sets it via SSH on a target computer:
ssh <user>@<target> "date --set '$(date)'"

This was working fine with various Ubuntu distros, but recently the target changed to another flavour of Linux and I get "invalid date" error.
What is the correct way to do this, which should work for any version of Linux?

You most likely also need to be certain to use the same locale.

Use NTP
The right thing is probably to stop what you're doing, and instead set up NTP on all of your computers. Most Linux distributions have had it enabled by default for a long time. It's integrated into systemd. With NTP, your computer will have the right time automatically, all the time. NTP is lightweight enough that even a typical home router has it, or at least has an NTP client that runs in a cron job.
For computers that are rarely online (a rarity these days), chrony works better than ntpd. (I don't know how well systemd's integrated NTP copes with a system that's rarely online.)
Why your current command doesn't always work
But assuming that for whatever reason you really need to set the time manually, read on. What you're currently doing is:

Print the current date and time on the local machine in the representation configured on your local account.
Transmit this textual representation of the date and time.
Parse the received date and time according to the rules on the remote machine.

This only works if the two systems' idea of the date and time representation are the same, or close enough. But there are two potential differences:

The systems may use a different format for the date and time, depending on the locale.
$ LC_ALL=en_US date
Tue Sep 24 09:52:51 PM CEST 2024
$ LC_ALL=en_GB date
Tue 24 Sep 21:52:53 CEST 2024
$ LC_ALL=fr_FR date
mar. 24 sept. 2024 21:52:56 CEST

If the locales don't match, then in theory not only the remote system may receive an invalid date, but it's possible that it could silently interpret the date incorrectly. For example, there may be a language whose abbreviated month name is the same as a different month in another language. I'm not aware of an actual case, but it's a risk.

The two systems may use a different time zone. Also, the remote system may not recognize the time zone name used by the local system. It's even possible that the time zone name on the local system could mean a different time zone on the remote system, so you could be setting a time that's hours off without realizing it.
$ TZ=Asia/Tel_Aviv date; TZ=Asia/Calcutta date
Sun Mar 24 22:28:58 IST 2024
Mon Mar 25 01:58:58 IST 2024



The locale is conveyed by environment variables. The locale command shows your locale settings. Note that running a non-interactive SSH command does not necessarily set the same environment as running an interactive shell: ssh user@target locale and echo date | ssh -i user@target may show different settings.
The time zone is usually configured at the system level, but can be overridden through the TZ environment variable.
How to copy the date reliably
To “copy” the date from one system to another, use a standard representation for the date. For the format, use the classic format that all Unix/POSIX versions of the date utility support: mmddHHMMyyyy (2-digit month, day, hour, minutes, and a 4-digit year). Although it isn't codified by POSIX, most implementations (including GNU, BSD and BusyBox) support setting seconds as well with a .SS suffix. Use the +FORMAT syntax on the local machine to print the date in that format. For the timezone, use GMT (a.k.a. UTC), which you can force by passing the -u option to date.
ssh root@target "date -u $(date -u +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S)"


If by timezone names, you mean those 3/4 letter codes used in some parts of the world such as GMT, CEST, then the most common are ambiguous. For instance date +%Z outputs CST  in most of China and parts of the USA (at least in Winter). The +0500 or -02:00 UTC offsets as used instead in some other parts of the world or in iso8601 are non-ambiguous.

The format I specify is the one that is universally accepted, and the other issue has an easy work-around (use -u as mentioned by @abligh).
However NTP is a far better solution in the normal IT case where both machines are connected to the internet or an NTP server.
The reason is not either of the above issues, but a different issue: the method above is only accurate to one second. If you repeatedly call it, say every hour, there is a real chance that the time will jump forwards or backwards by one second each time, which might cause chaos. I can't use NTP, my target is in orbit!

Based on the information here, the following method should work in any systems that support the GNU Core Utilities (which covers all common distros).
Note that --set is not used when setting the date.
MY_DATE=$(date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S)
ssh <user>@<target> "date '${MY_DATE}'"


Can't you just do ssh <user>@<target> "date '$(date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S)'" in a single command as you were doing before?

I strongly suggest using date -u in both cases, particularly if the machines might have different timezone settings. This can also be necessary over the periods of summertime adjustment.

Alternatively, use seconds since the Epoch: date +%s

@terdon yes you can - I just thought it was more readable as two lines. The important points are the format, and the lack of --set.

@Peterbill I'm not sure this will work for setting the time - the only time format that seemed to be guaranteed to work was the weird month-day-hour-minute-year-second one above.

@abligh great point, thank you
